# For every line beginning with 4 spaces, add text-indent tags

Tags: php, regex, indentation

I've got text where some lines are indented with 4 spaces. I've been trying to write a regex which would find every line beginning with 4 spaces and put a `<span class="indented">` at the beginning and a `</span>` at the end. I'm no good at regex yet, though, so it came to nothing. Is there a way to do it?

(I'm working in PHP, in case there's an option easier than regex).

Example:

```
Text text text
    Indented text text text
More text text text
A bit more text text.
```

to:

```
Text text text
<span class="indented">Indented text text text</span>
More text text text
A bit more text text.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will match lines starting with at least 4 spaces or a tab character:

```
$str = preg_replace("/^(?: {4,}|\t *)(.*)$/m", "<span class=\"indented\">$1</span>", $str);
```

Comment: I would find it more expressive to say (?: {4}|\t).  Makes it easier to determine how many spaces you're actually targeting.  (Might even just go \s{4})

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks so much. That's much more complex regex than I can even get my head around, but it works great.

Comment: @RC.:  `\s{4}` is a possibility, however that would mean at least 4 tab characters would have to be matched for it work, which doesn't seem practical.

Comment: I meant that as a replacement to just the first part.  You would still leave the |\t.  I was just lazy and didn't write out the whole thing again. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar, and one thing I might suggest is changing the goal formatting to be

```
<span class="tab"></span>Indented text text text
```

You can then set your css something like `.tab {width:4em;}` and instead of using preg_replace and regexes, you can do

```
str_replace($str, "    ", "<span class='tab'></span>");
```

This has the benefit of allowing for 8 spaces to turn into a double width tab easily.

Comment: `span` is an inline element, it's not affected by `width:`

Comment: That's an idea, too... it'd work with an inline div. Seems a bit simpler than dragging out regex.

Comment: You're right, you'd have to also make the span `display:inline-block;`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
//get each line as an item in an array
$array_of_lines = explode("\n", $your_string_of_lines);

foreach($array_of_lines as $line) {
    // First four characters
    $first_four = substr($line, 0, 4);
    if($first_four == '    ') {
        $line = trim($line);
        $line = '<span class="indented">'.$line.'</span>'; 
    }

    $output[] = $line;
}

echo implode("\n",$output);
```